# Rabin-Karp Algorithm in PHP

Tags: php, string, algorithm, rabin-karp

I was wondering if anyone can share a source for Rabin-Karp algorithm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm

http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~ellard/Q-97/HTML/root/node43.html

Here's a couple sources.

Comment: @Gabe: yep, wikipedia already has a psuedocode source. and if you want to use php as your tag suggests, it is powerful enough to pretty much translate that algorithm line by line.

Answer (score 1):

This is a port of [this C implementation of the Karp-Rabin algorithm](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node5.html):

```
function KR($haystack, $needle) {
    $n = strlen($haystack);
    $m = strlen($needle);
    if ($m > $n) {
        return -1;
    }
    /* Preprocessing */
    $d = 1 << ($m - 1);
    for ($hh = $hn = $i = 0; $i < $m; ++$i) {
        $hh = (($hh<<1) + ord($haystack[$i]));
        $hn = (($hn<<1) + ord($needle[$i]));
    }
    /* Searching */
    $j = 0;
    while ($j <= $n-$m) {
        if ($hh == $hn && substr($haystack, $j, $m) === $needle) {
            return $j;
        }
        if ($j === $n-$m) {
            return false;
        }
        /* Rehashing */
        $hh = (($hh - ord($haystack[$j]) * $d) << 1) + ord($haystack[$j + $m]);
        ++$j;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is the most elegant and readable solution. I've added a modified version below with a little bit more clarification.

Comment: Super solution, but one thing I don't quite get is what is the purpose of $d?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly altered version Gumbo's answer above, with simpler hashing and clearer variable naming, for the sake of illustration.

In the illustrative hashing below I'm just adding the ord() value of each character to a number, which represents the hash, then subtracting that value/adding the ord() of the next char when advancing our search. **This is very collision-prone** (and therefore not good for production), but it's easier to understand if you're just learning Rabin-Karp conceptually.

```
function rk ($needle, $haystack)
{
    $nlen = strlen($needle);
    $hlen = strlen($haystack);
    $nhash = 0;
    $hhash = 0;

    // Special cases that don't require the rk algo:
    // if needle is longer than haystack, no possible match
    if ($nlen > $hlen) {
        return false;
    }
    // If they're the same size, they must just match
    if ($nlen == $hlen) {
        return ($needle === $haystack);
    }

    // Compute hash of $needle and $haystack[0..needle.length]
    // This is a very primitive hashing method for illustrative purposes
    // only. You'll want to modify each value based on its position in
    // the string as per Gumbo's example above (left shifting)
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nlen; ++$i) {
        $nhash += ord($needle[$i]);
        $hhash += ord($haystack[$i]);
    }

    // Go through each position of needle and see if
    // the hashes match, then do a comparison at that point
    for ($i = 0, $c = $hlen - $nlen; $i <= $c; ++$i) {
        // If the hashes match, there's a good chance the next $nlen characters of $haystack matches $needle
        if ($nhash == $hhash && $needle === substr($haystack, $i, $nlen)) {
            return $i;
        }
        // If we've reached the end, don't try to update the hash with
        // the code following this if()
        if ($i == $c) {
            return false;
        }

        // Update hhash to the next position by subtracting the
        // letter we're removing and adding the letter we're adding
        $hhash = ($hhash - ord($haystack[$i])) + ord($haystack[$i + $nlen]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out.  You will have to strip the punctuation from the `$needle` and `$haystack` before sending it to `match_rabinKarp()`, but this basically follows the algorithm given on the wikipedia page.

```
// this hash function is friendly, according to the wikipedia page
function hash($string) {
 $base = ord('a');
 if (strlen($string) == 1) {
  return ord($string);
 } else {
  $result = 0;
  // sum each of the character*(base^i)
  for ($i=strlen($string)-1; $i>=0; $i++) {
   $result += $string[$i]*pow($base,$i);
  }
  return $result;
 }
}
// perform the actual match
function match_rabinKarp($needle, $haystack) {
 $needle = substr($needle);      // remove capitals
 $haystack = substr($haystack);  // remove capitals
 $m = strlen($needle);           // length of $needle
 $n = strlen($haystack);         // length of $haystack
 $h_haystack = hash($haystack);  // hash of $haystack
 $h_needle = hash($needle);      // hash of $needle
 // whittle away at the $haystack until we find a match
 for ($i=0;$i<$n-$m+1;$i++) {
  if ($h_needle == $h_haystack) {
   if (substr($haystack,$i,$i+$m-1) == $needle) {
    return $i;
   }
  }
 }
 return false;
}
```